# Delphi (RAD Studio XE2): How can I print the contents of a DBGrid or ADOQuery?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

On the program I am working on for a school project, there is a results page which displays the contents of a database in a DBGrid using a ADOQuery component.  I have a button on the page which when I click it, it should print whatever the contents of the DBGrid is with a printer.

The printer setup is already done with a PrintDialog component, I know how to do that part, the problem is finding a way to print the contents of DBGrid.

The desired result would be to print all the data in the DBGrid, not just that shown on screen but whatever might be found if you scroll down in the DBGrid, as it is shown on the DBGrid onto a page, that could be printed to a physical paper or a electronic document, as chosen in the PrintDialog component.

I'll check up on the FastReports thing as suggested by some commentors.  Does that have any dependancies when the program is run on another computer, as in does the computer also need FastReports installed?

Is this possible?  If it is, how?  Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

I'm sorry if the question was/is not clear enough, I thought it was clear enough but that just goes to show how inexperienced I am.

Comment: Do you want to print what is on the grid on a printer or something OR do you want to show data on the grid?

Comment: I forgot to say that, yes I want to print what is on the grid with a printer.  I'll edit my original post to clear out the uncertainty

Comment: Almost all versions of Delphi come with some kind of report generator. Earlier versions have `Quick Report`, then they switched to `Rave Report` and now Delphi comes integrated with `Fast Report`. Update tags of your question and include the exact Delphi version you're using so we can provide specific instructions related for report generator available to you.

Comment: @LightBulb: The (Delphi XE2) in the title and tags isn't enough to give you the "exact Delphi version"? :-)

Comment: Are you trying to print all of the data that's in the ADOQuery result set, or just the ones currently being displayed in the grid on screen? They're two different things, and knowing which you mean matters for the answer. Printing the results of a query is different than printing a few rows and columns from a grid. (The grid might currently show 10 rows of 5 columns on the screen, while the query it's attached to contains 100 rows of 10 columns. Which do you want to print?)

Comment: Well, for the purposes the program is going to be used for, printing just what is shown on screen might work, since the data most probably won't exceed the amount the grid can display at a time. But I do think it'd be better to print the entire result, just in case the teacher assessing it actually adds like 100 records of test data or something.

Comment: It's still difficult to know what you're asking, because you've not clarified it despite repeated requests to do so. Presuming that your last comment means "print a tabular report (columns of data in rows down a page)", Fast Reports would be the built-in solution. If you'll [edit] your question to confirm that your question is actually about a tabular report, someone here can probably help you get started (or you can read the documentation in the Fast Report Users Guide, found in Start->All Programs->Fast Reports on your machine).